# POST 500 internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to learn how to pass value from jquery to controller and insert it in database instead of passing value from form to controller in laravel 5.4 but unfortunately i got this error saying:

POST http://x.x.x.x:x/addtable 500 (Internal Server Error).

this is my blade file: SampleInsert.blade.php

```
{{csrf_field()}}
<input type="text" id="sample2"  required>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick = "submit();"> SUBMIT</button>
  <a href="{{ url ('/') }}"><button type="button" class="button"> Cancel</button></a>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
function submit() {
  var samp = Array();
    samp[ 0 ] = 1;
    samp[ 1 ] = 'a';
    samp[ 2 ] =  document.getElementById( "sample2" )
    .value;
    samp[ 3 ] = 2;
    samp[ 4 ] = 3;

  var sample = JSON.stringify( samp );
  $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: '/addtable',
      data: {
          pSample: sample
      },
      success: function ( result ) {
          alert( 'Success' );
          alert( result );
      }
  } );
} //submit();
```

addtable controller:

```
public function addTable(){
  $sample = json_decode(Input::get('pSample'));
  $sample1 = $sample[0];
  $sample2 = $sample[1];
  $sample3 = $sample[2];

  print_r($sample3);
  print_r($sample);
}
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Do use jQuery when it's available: `samp[2] =  $("#sample2").val();` Also never cal anything submit - you may want to use the submit event of an actual form and have issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code like this:

```
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Then, You need to make an ajax request, use the beforeSend method.

```
$("#try").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("data-link");
    $.ajax({
        url: "test",
        type:"POST",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
            if (token) {
              return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
            }
        },
        data: { testdata : 'testdatacontent' },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },error:function(){ 
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    }); //end of ajax
});
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SampleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Receive data here
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function addTable(Request $request) { 
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            //$request->input('field_name_here');
            $sample = $request->input('pSample');
            print_r($sample); 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I copied your beforeSend to my ajax and copied also your meta to my header but i still get the error.

Comment: You try simple echo like this and check again:  `public function addTable(){
  echo "Wroking";
}`

Comment: Use this code in controller: `public function addTable(Request $request)
{
 if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
  $sample = $request->input('pSample');
  print_r($sample);
 }
}`

Comment: You also need to include namespace: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: `Input::get('field');` is not available in laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

see [csrf-x-csrf-token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)